# Google Docs spreadsheet formula for most frequent keywords

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, formula

I wonder if there is a formula in Google Docs Spreadsheet which could identify and display (for example in column D) the most frequent (key)words in a spreadsheet?

Let's say that I have a column (Column B) full of tweets (see example image) and I would like to find top keywords in the column B and display them in column D. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To return the top 10 individual words in column B, with their frequency, try:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ";B3:B);" ")&{"";""});"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 10 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'";0))`

Comment: AdamL...once again thank you for your help. Formula works just fine. Just one quick question - is there a way to exclude some words like and OR is?

Comment: You could enter some conditions into the QUERY clause: `"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != 'and' and Col1 != 'is' group by..."` or alternatively `"select Col1, count(Col2) where not(Col1 matches 'and|is') group by..."`.

Comment: This doesn't ignore case, how do I make this query case insensitive?

Comment: If you're OK with words being displayed in, say, lower case, try wrapping the `B3:B` in `LOWER()`.

Comment: Great formula! Is there a limit to the numbers of rows it can handle ? I have the impression it has one, 634 in my case, depense on what is in the cells.

Comment: How to avoid `Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.`?

Comment: @AdamL can you answer stallingOne his question please?

Comment: @stallingOne @Fabian apologies for missing this. There has been a bit of change since this post that makes the solution a bit more straightforward. There is also a hack that gets around the 50k character limit of manufactured strings. Both should be addressed with `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(B3:B,,9^9)," ")),"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Word', count(Col1) 'Frequency'",0)`. I'll monitor follow-up comments, and edit my answer with this updated formula if appropriate.

Comment: @AdamL Is there a way to make the QUERY check against a blacklist of words contained within the sheet? It seems as though there’s a limit to how “where not” options you can include, but when using this for analysing prose, there’s a lot of prepositions and definite articles getting sucked in (to, from, by, a, the, etc.) which I’d want to exclude, and it’d be great if I could update the blacklist in cells rather than editing the formula itself.