# How do I remove rows with special characters from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, special-characters, google-sheets-query

Thanks for the help. I have a large-ish data set where I am trying to query a long column of 2-3 word phrases.

I am using the following code to try and pick out the frequency of the repeated words. Example data below.

My issue is that the code is not resolving - I think it is because there are some special characters in the data.

Some Japanese, some copy-right signs, URLs, and greek symbols.

1) Is there a way to easily remove rows with special characters?

2) Am I doing something else incorrectly?

3) How would I do the same frequency formula I have here - but with two word phrases and three word phases?

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ";B3:B);" ")& . 
{"";""});"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) 
desc limit 10 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'";0))
```

[image: Example Data]

I received the code from here, btw.
[Google Docs spreadsheet formula for most frequent keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307125/google-docs-spreadsheet-formula-for-most-frequent-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the extra "." the formula seems to refer to the wrong column. Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",A:A)," ")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'",0))
```

This also counts all, not just the  top 10.

I don't think this approach will work for two word phrases.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the help. The code I have provided works with data that doesn't have special characters in it. I simply need to know how to remove the rows with special characters without going through manually. Your suggested code didn't work either

Comment: Any special characters I try work fine. Can you give an example of what does not work?